# WPF window reports old left property after DragMove

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So i have this issue, after calling <kbd>DragMove()</kbd>, the window reports its old `Left` property as if DragMove did not change it at all.

so lets say the window's left is currently 100 pixels,
i move the window using <kbd>DragMove()</kbd>:

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        DragMove();
    }
}
```

after which i click a button an show the new Left position of the window:

```
private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        MessageBox.Show(Left.ToString());
}
```

however, the Message box still shows '100' as if the window didnt move at all although it did...

what am i missing?

Comment: Value seems to update for me within a similar test project, are you defining `Left` somewhere else, or is your button hosted within another control with a `Left` property?

Comment: i found the issue, i was animating the left property and it seems to have been stuck on that value, had to reset animation after finish... thanks for looking though

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found the issue, i was  animating the `Left` property and for some reason the `Left` would keep reporting the same post-animation value even after moving the window with DragMove().

to get it to work i had to remove the animation from the form once it has finished as follows:

```
DoubleAnimation _leftAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

//...animation settings...

_leftAnimation.Completed += delegate(object animSender, EventArgs animE)
{
    BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, null);
};

this.BeginAnimation(LeftProperty, _leftAnimation);
```